# Salesforce ANT migration tool login failure

Tags: migration-tool, ant

We want to use ANT migration tool for our deployment. I have set it up but whenever I am trying to deploy the package, I get the following error:

BUILD FAILED
Failed to login: Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0

I checked my username, password and security token but that does not seem to be the issue. We have an office firewall.
How do i bypass this issue? 
Any help will be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered HaoIDE (https://github.com/xjsender/haoide) with Sublime Text 3? The setup is easier and maybe you could at minimum verify a connection can be made just fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure [Ant proxy settings](http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html). Standard way is to set the environment variable ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"